# htaccess check url and reconstruct it on specific condition

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible with `.htaccess` to check if a URL has a certain path and then reconstruct it?

My issue is that I need to take a URL in this format:

```
https://example.com/subdirectory/group/test_1
```

and if the URL matches:

```
https://example.com/subdirectory/group/
```

without the hash to reconstruct the URL adding the hash to be:

```
https://example.com/subdirectory/#/group/test_1
```

so in essence I would be checking if the URL is:

```
https://example.com/subdirectory/group/
```

and if it is changing it to be:

```
https://example.com/subdirectory/#/group/
```

Comment: Please do add your tried htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: Sure that is possible. You will find literally _thousands_ of existing examples for such rewriting setup here on SO. Or in any "how to" about rewriting URL you find on google. You just need to adapt one of those to your specific need.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(group/.*) /subdirectory/#/$1 [R=302,NE]
```

That rule should basically do the trick.

`R=302` for testing, make that into a 301 once you verified it works properly.

The `NE` / noescape flag is necessary, so that the `#` stays a `#`, and doesn't get escaped to `%23`.